# What attributes does Jesus have from an LDS doctrinal perspective that are different from the Jesus in the Holy Trinity?

Tags: life-of-jesus, lds, trinity

I ask this because when I read about the attributes of Jesus in the Trinity and compare him to the Jesus as explained by Mormon doctrine I find very little difference. With that being said if there are differences, how do they effect his divinity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this, in regards to Jesus Christ's divinity, would be:  There is little to no difference.  The differences in Mormon theology do not alter the way Christ's Divinity is regarded by Mormons vs. the regard given by Trinitarians.  Trinitarians and Mormons both view Christ as Divine, and the Most Divine Possible.

I will provide some background, and also explain one potentially insignificant perceived difference that comes to my mind.

While the Mormon Church may believe that the Trinity are 3 separate beings with the same purpose, as opposed to 3 forms of the same being (possibly an oversimplification, but the Trinity is difficult for me to explain) The role of Jesus Christ is the same, through him and him alone comes Salvation.  He is Divine.  He is God.  (From of Mormon perspective you might alter that to say, he is "a God")  It it through his merits that all mankind may be saved and live Happily in the afterlife (slightly different perspective on afterlife for Mormons and Mainstream Christinity)

One specific attribute that may be a little (or a lot) different, is the existence of Jesus Christ's physical body.  Mormons Believe he still has one, a Divine immortal body that is inseparable from his spirit.  Mainstream Christian religious belief may not agree with this idea.  I've met pastors who have said that Christ only took a physical form while on earth, and once ascended to heaven returned to a spirit, or spiritual form, and that we too will be like that while in Heaven.

Mormons believe the physical form and spiritual form together will be the final Divine form.  Not a mortal physical body, but an immortal physical body.  Mormons will refer to this body as a Celestial, Perfected or a Glorified Body.   You'd find information about this in The Doctrine and Covenants, a publication from the LDS Church.  It's also been repeated by LDS Apostles and Prophets throughout the years.

The difference in Mainstream Christian or more specifically Trinitarian beliefs vs. Mormon beliefs on Christ's Divine physical form may be the biggest difference, if and when it's a difference at all.

The following link may suggest that the difference I perceive is not really a difference:  [Jesus Ressurection Was Physical](http://carm.org/jesus-resurrection-was-physical)

Here is an Official LDS statement on who Jesus Christ is, and his Divine purpose:  [The Living Christ](http://jesuschrist.lds.org/SonOfGod/eng/testimonies-of-him/articles/the-living-christ-the-testimony-of-the-apostles-of-the-church-of-jesus-christ-of-latter-day-saints)

Answer (score 0):

Latter Day Saints believe in a doctrine of the trinity which is articulated as the Godhead being ["unified in purpose"](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-7-the-holy-ghost?lang=eng) but not in personage. This is very different than the doctrine of the trinity as articulated in the [Nicene Creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed#Comparison_between_Creed_of_325_and_Creed_of_381) which is rejected by the LDS church. Therefore, I think what you are really asking is "What attributes does Jesus have from an LDS doctrinal perspective that are different from the Jesus in the Evangelical, Catholic and Protestant perspective?"

There are a couple significant differences between Jesus that Latter Day Saints(LDS) believe in and Jesus Christ taught by Catholics, Protestants and Evangelicals.

Some Differences are as follows:

**The LDS church teaches that Jesus is Son of God in the same way as you and I are - this means we were Jesus Spirit Brother and we can become like him and become Exhaled like him**

See Gospel Principles Chapters [2](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-2-our-heavenly-family?lang=eng) and [47](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-47-exaltation?lang=eng)

In contrast the Nicene creed states "We believe in one God, the Father Almighty, Maker of heaven and earth, and of all things visible and invisible. And in one Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God, begotten of the Father the only-begotten; that is, of the essence of the Father, God of God, Light of Light, very God of very God, begotten, not made, being of one substance with the Father;"

**The LDS church teaches that Jesus is a Creation of God**

Doctrines of the Gospel [Chapter 4](https://www.lds.org/manual/doctrines-of-the-gospel-student-manual/chapter-4-jesus-christ-the-son-of-god?lang=eng) states that "Jesus Christ is literally the son of God the Eternal Father.'Among the spirit children of Elohim, the first-born was and is Jehovah, or Jesus Christ, to whom all others are juniors'"

Again, in contrast the Nicene creed states that "those who say: 'There was a time when he [the son] was not;' and 'He was not before he was made;' ... they are condemned by the holy catholic and apostolic Church.

**The LDS church also believes Lucifer (The Devil) is a Brother and equal of Jesus**

Gospel Principles [Chapter 3](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-3-jesus-christ-our-chosen-leader-and-savior?lang=eng) states that Satan offered a competing plan to Jesus for salvation - "Satan, who was called Lucifer, also came, saying, “Behold, here am I, send me, I will be thy son, and I will redeem all mankind, that one soul shall not be lost, and surely I will do it; wherefore give me thine honor” (Moses 4:1). Satan wanted to force us all to do his will. Under his plan, we would not be allowed to choose." The Catholic, Evangelical and Protestant teaching on Satan either simply does not speculate on the Devil's origins or is based on Milton's [Paradise Lost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Lost).

**The LDS church teaches Christ atoned on the Cross and also in the Garden of Gethsemane**

True to the Faith states on page 17 "Jesus Atoning sacrifice took place in the Garden of Gethsemane and on the cross at Calvary. In Gethsemane He submitted to the will of the father and began to take upon himself the sins of all people.

**Finally, the LDS church teaches [Universal Reconciliation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_reconciliation) and that Jesus sins covered all**

In True to the Faith on page 18, it states "Jesus Christ redeems all people from the effects of the Fall. All people who have ever lived on the earth and who ever will live on the earth will be resurrected and brought back into the presence of God to be judged (see  2 Nephi 2:5-10;  Helaman 14:15-17). Through the Savior's gift of mercy and redeeming grace, we will all receive the gift of immortality and live forever in glorified, resurrected bodies"

While this is not [necessarily unique to Mormonism, it is rejected by all but a few denominations and sects of Catholicism, Evangelicalism and Protestantism.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_reconciliation#History)

Comment: 4 downvotes and I'm the first to comment? Aren't we supposed to say why the answer is poor quality? Obviously this answer needs help, and I add my downvote, but should we provide feedback in case this is not obvious to some readers?

Comment: @Matt , Please are you correcting or criticizing my answer or saying it doesn't address the question....I don't understand as am a new User...I should edit it now but also would like to know your thoughts......Humbly,  John

Comment: Well, partly it's the community's fault for not providing helpful feedback, so I apologize for that. The question, then, is asking if there are differences between LDS beliefs of Jesus and "mainstream" Christianity's beliefs of Jesus, how does that affect His *divinity*? This answer doesn't really address the question. Instead, you're pinning LDS belief against the Bible, which is contrary to the objective nature of this site. Revise your answer so it is more neutral and on-topic for this question.

Comment: Matt, first, your origional post used some alienating language. I have edited the post a bit in this regard. For example, I have changed "They" to "The LDS church" Secondly, you cited Bible verses as the basis for your claims. While all of your claims are accurate, the LDS use the same Bible as you and I with some additional scripture. That is probably why you were downvoted so heavily. I instead compared early church statements with official LDS church teachings so as to better support your points. I have also added one additional difference. I hope you like these edits.

Comment: @user3127174 Your edits have vastly improved this answer. Good work.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that is actually John's post.

Comment: "Lucifer is a brother of Jesus" is true, but only in the same sense that Mormons believe that Jesus is "brother" to all children of God. "Equal to Jesus" is a bit of a stretch, though I suppose it depends on what you are comparing on. Paul used the term "joint-heirs with Christ".